# Firebase auth for accessing GCP BigQuery

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-authentication

I have firebase project and an android app created from it.  App user gets signed up by email method.
Each user has some structured data in the form of csv. Each user can have many such CSV. I can put them into Cloud storage bucket. User may read a column from CSV at any point.

1. Can i create direct bigQuery table for each CSV from firebase app ? if yes can i access control bigquery table with firebase auth.
2. Will it be cost effective ? (Considering that user may read a column from CSV/Table at any point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cover the question from your title and "can i access control bigquery table with firebase auth?", the answer is: no.

- Firebase Authentication signs users in using an ID token, which is a JWT.
- BigQuery requires users that are signed in with Google Authentication, which is OAuth2 based.
- You can't use the ID token from Firebase Authentication to access BigQuery.

The closest you can get is when the user signs in to Firebase with a Google account, in which case you can intercept the OAuth token - and then use *that* to access BigQuery.

The more likely approach though is to create custom server-side code to handle the CSV ingestion, and the access control to the resulting tables. If you then create a custom API endpoint to allow the users of your app to call the functionality, that's where you'd [decode and verify the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) and implement your authorization logic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  My current implementation is the exactly same as what you suggested. But I was getting double sure on if there is direct integration of big query  in firebase alike Cloud storage.
Appreciated your quick response.   Thank you.